# Using Trigger.new List and Map compare new contracts with old contracts

Tags: trigger, list, map

I'm trying to compare dates of old contracts and new contracts (trigger.new) from the same account, the new contracts are imported and are from a lot of different accounts. But the performance of it has to be better. So I was thinking to do a map of old contracts that compare by the AccountId and not iterate all contracts every time. Below is my code so far. Is it possible to do it using a map, maybe like `Map <Id, List<Contract>>` ? And how I iterate over a map like this one?

```
public class NewContracts {

public static void comparingContracts(List<Contract> newContracts){

    Set<String> setAccounts = new set<String>();
    list<Contract> oldContracts = new list<Contract>();


    for (Contract c: newContracts){
        setAccounts.add(c.AccountId);
    } 

    oldContracts = [SELECT AccountId, EndDate, RecordTypeId FROM Contract WHERE AccountId in :setAccounts];

    for(Contract oCon: oldContracts){

        for(Contract nCon: newContracts){                            
            if (oCon.AccountId == nCon.AccountId ){
                nCon.checkTest__c= compareDate(oCon.EndDate, nCon.StartDate);   
            }               
        }  
    }  
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. It requires a three step process that I call the [Aggregate Query Update](https://sfdcfox.blogspot.com/2017/03/the-aggregate-query-update-pattern.html) pattern.

```
public static void comparingContracts(List<Contract> newContracts) {
    Map<Id, Contract[]> oldContracts = new Map<Id, Contract[]>();
    // Aggregate
    for(Contract record: newContracts) {
        oldContracts.put(record.AccountId, new Contract[0]);
    }
    // Query 
    for(Contract record: [SELECT AccountId, EndDate, RecordTypeId FROM Contract WHERE AccountId in :oldContracts.keySet()]) {
        oldContracts.get(record.AccountId).add(record);
    }
    // Update
    for(Contract record: newContracts) {
        for(Contract oldRecord: oldContracts.get(record.AccountId)) {
            record.CheckTest__c = compareDate(oldRecord.EndDate, record.StartDate);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much,  it helps me a lot.

Comment: But in case I have to compare among the new contracts of the same account too. Let's suppose the list of new contracts have 3 contracts of the same account and between two of them return true from compareDate function. In that case I can accomplish it just adding a third For loop after the second For from Update? That will make my code very slow right? Thanks again for the help dude.

Comment: @AliasX I don't think you should have a problem with it. The main problem you want to avoid are exponential loops, where looping over, for example, 200 x 200 records results in 40,000 iterations.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm worried about. Maybe I'll have 2.000 records at once. I know that trigger will process 200 at time but will happen what you just said, 200 x 200 (not counting the iteration with old contracts).

Comment: @AliasX If you want, I can review the final product, but as long as you're not looping over one large list within another large list, you'll be fine.